# Xamarin Example Layout : Tabs with buttons

Tags: xamarin, rounded-corners

I want to have tabs in my app where I can put a button next to the label. The button will sort the data in the current tab . I found nothing standard in Xamarin about tabs , I thought of putting two buttons next to each other , one with the label and the other with the icon of ordering , both with rounded corners to look like a tab . I made a drawing to illustrate what I want to do.

[image: button in the tab]

I would like to know if this is possible with xaml xamarin forms or C#. Should I give up with xamarin forms and do native Xamarin on each platform?